# Format dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss in a datapicker c#

Tags: c#, format, datapicker

I'm trying to insert a record in a database (Sql Server 2008) and I need to insert my date with the format dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

I'm trying to format the value of a datapicker. This is my code:

```
public Manas()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    datep.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
    datep.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
}            

sbQuery1S.Append("UPDATE AC SET date= '" + datep.Value.ToString() + "' WHERE NTIVO='" + txtct.Text.ToString() + "' AND NUMA ='" + txia.Text.ToString() + "' AND NUIPO='" + txtpo.Text.ToString() + "' AND SUACT='" + txtSNum.Text.ToString() + "'");
                cmd1S.CommandText = sbQuery1S.ToString();
                cmd1S.Connection = conn;
                cmd1S.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem is that the format of the data picker is dd//MM/yy hh:mm:ss

Any idea about how can I change it?

Comment: You've set it clearly there in `CustomFormat`.. to change it.. change that string.

Comment: "i need to insert my date with the format dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" Um, why?  Why are you saving date/time values to a database as text?  Why are you not using a type specifically intended for the purpose, i.e. datetime or datetime2?

Comment: I need dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss and it gives me dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss ... Note the "yy" @Simon Whitehead

Comment: @jmcilhinney Is it wrong? It's a "datetime"

Comment: Is it wrong to store date/time values as text?  Absolutely.  Do you store numbers as text?  If not then why would you store dates/times as text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never ever do this as it will cause SQL-injections vulnerability. You have to use parameters

```
cmd1S.CommandText = "UPDATE AC SET date = @p1 WHERE NTIVO = @p2 AND NUMA = @p3 AND NUIPO=@p4 AND SUACT=@p5";
var p1 = cmd1S.CreateParameter();
p1.Name = "p1";
p1.Value =  DateTime.ParseExact(datep.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
cmd1S.Parameters.Add(p1);
//other parameters
cmd1S.Connection = conn;
cmd1S.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I did it, but now it says `error en una parte del formato de fecha expression (if known) =`